# Hide action bar in overlay mode, in combination with tab strip

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, scrollview

I have a layout with a custom tabstrip (com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip) and a ScrollView.

What I want to do is: when the user scrolls down, the action bar should hide (translate up); when the user scrolls up again, the action bar should reappear.

I don't want the ScrollView to slide along with the actionbar. For this I used the Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY flag, placing it under the actionbar. All works nicely this way, except for the fact that my custom tabstrip is initially hidden under the actionbar, only to appear when I scroll down.
Is there any way the tabstrip could be located under the actionbar initially, and slide along up when the actionbar is hidden? The ScrollView should be located under the actionbar at all times.

Comment: Ok, for now I added a synchronized animation that translates my tab strip upwards when the actionBar is hiding; and downwards again when it is showing.Not the solution I was hoping for, so if there are better, please let me know.